# Google Map CameraUpdate to center a certain location

Tags: android, google-maps

I went through this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory) for CameraUpdateFactory and I am interested in using `newLatLngBounds` method.
What am I trying to achieve?

1. Should see all the locations passed in as a list on the map.
2. Keeping the map centered at a say 1st element of the list.

What `newLatLngBounds` does is that it calculates the center on its own and doesn't have a public method to explicitly set it.

---

(Added to address clarity)

How to generate a `LatLngBounds` such that when invoking

```
CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, padding)
```

the result is the **minimal-bounded map display *centered on a point of my choosing*** rather than the center being computed by the LatLngBounds.Builder.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few calculations you can achieve the desired result.  (Reference [SphericalUtil](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html) for utility functions mentioned.)

### Summary

(a) Compute the bounding box of all your points (NW and SW corner points) (X).

(b) Compute the max distance from desired centered point to east-west sides of X and north-south sides.

(c) Using max distance pair to compute the new lat-lng extents - your latLngBounds (Z).

(d) Use `newLatLngBounds` with computed bounds (Z).

### Picture

[image]

### Details

So to compute the bounding box loop over your list of points and keep the northern and southern most latitude and keep the western and eastern most longitude.  This is X.

To compute (A) use `SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween` to compute the distance from desired center point to Xeast and Xwest and determine max of these two distances (A).  Similarly compute the distance from desired center point to Xnorth and Xsouth and determine max of these two distances (B).

Use the computed max distances (A,B) to derive new points using `SphericalUtil.computeOffset` using center point and max distances and either 90 (or 270) and 0 (or 180) for headings (in the example diagram 270 to get A' and 0 to get B').

You now have the new bounding box (Z) to use as the LatLngBounds which is centered on your desired point.

## Snippets

Assume `pts` is a list of points to be displayed.

Build bounding box X

```
    LatLng Xnw = pts.get(0);
    LatLng Xse = Xnw;

    for (LatLng p : pts) {
        if (p.latitude > Xnw.latitude) {
            Xnw = new LatLng(p.latitude,Xnw.longitude);
        }
        if (p.latitude < Xse.latitude) {
            Xse = new LatLng(p.latitude,Xse.longitude);
        }
        if (p.longitude < Xnw.longitude) {
            Xnw = new LatLng(Xnw.latitude, p.longitude);
        }
        if (p.longitude > Xse.longitude) {
            Xse = new LatLng(Xse.latitude, p.longitude);
        }
    }
```

Pick an arbitrary center

```
   LatLng c = pts.get(3);
```

Compute Z

```
    double dA0 = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(c, new LatLng(c.latitude, Xse.longitude));
    double dA1 = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(c, new LatLng(c.latitude, Xnw.longitude));
    double dB0 = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(c, new LatLng(Xse.latitude, c.longitude));
    double dB1 = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(c, new LatLng(Xnw.latitude, c.longitude));

    LatLng Znw = c;
    LatLng Zse = c;

    // Z longitude
    double dA = Math.max(dA0, dA1);
    Zse = new LatLng(Zse.latitude, SphericalUtil.computeOffset(c, dA, 90).longitude);
    Znw = new LatLng(Znw.latitude, SphericalUtil.computeOffset(c, dA, 270).longitude);

    double dB = Math.max(dB0, dB1);
    Zse = new LatLng(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(c, dB, 180).latitude, Zse.longitude);
    Znw = new LatLng(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(c, dB, 0).latitude, Znw.longitude);
```

Create latLngBounds by adding Z along with points.

```
    LatLngBounds.Builder llbb = LatLngBounds.builder();
    for (LatLng p : pts) {
        llbb.include(p);
        MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions().position(p);

        if (p.equals(c)) {
            mo.title("C");
        }
        mMap.addMarker(mo);
    }
    llbb.include(Znw);
    llbb.include(Zse);
```

## Sample (centered on 'c')

[image]

## Sample (without centering)

[image]